# Can I let my fixed header scroll, the moment a collapsible header is no longer on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, collapsable

We've all seen the collapsible headers a lot now a days. I really like the effect it brings to a page, it gives a lot more dept.
I would like to achieve this dept effects, but I don't really need the functionality of a fixed header.

Now I've seen collapsible headers done, with the fixed header becoming smaller as soon as the collapsible header is off the page.
Is it possible to make the fixed header no longer fixed, the moment the collapsible header is off the page? And make it scroll off the page with the rest of the content?

Comment: We need some code to work up with... What are you upto...

Comment: I have yet to write the code, but it will be similar to [this tutorial](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/header-effect/final-demo/index.html). Only that I want the header to start scrolling as soon as the image is off screen.

Comment: Please show some sort of effort and preliminary research before posting questions...

Comment: This is actually part of the research. I know how to do the collapsible header effect. I don't know how to affect the header once something is off screen, nor do I know any search terms to search for such an effect. I'm not looking for copy-paste ready code, I'm asking for input on methods of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it and I hope this is what you want.. Click the link below for Demo..

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zDEef/)

This is the HTML

```
<div id="headerSlideContainer">

    <div id="headerSlideContent">

        Header content goes here!

    </div>
    <div id="new">
        Other Contents
    </div>

</div>
```

n here goes CSS..

```
#headerSlideContainer {
    position: absolute;

    top:0px;
    width: 100%;

   height:1000px;
    background: black;
}
#headerSlideContent {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    background:Red;
    z-index:10000;
    position:fixed;
}

#new{
    top:60px;
    z-index:2;
    height:100px;
    background:Orange;
    position:absolute;
    color: white;

}
```

n this is the Javascript..

```
$(function() {

    var bar = $('#headerSlideContainer');
    var top = bar.css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : '5px'}, 500);
        } else {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: scrollTop() was what I was looking for. Didn't think that was basic jquery functionality. Thanks a lot!